# redis container how to load lua script from host

Tags: redis, lua

I am trying to execute a lua script against a redis instance running in a container.  The code is very simple 2 liner example.

```lua
local foo = redis.call("ping")
return foo
```

As this file is on the host machine, how do i get it to execute inside docker exec ?  Or should I install redis-cli locally to test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understood what you want. You have a Lua script on your docker host that you want to load into Redis running inside a docker container without needing `redis-cli` on the host.

So, start the official Redis in a container as a daemon:

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis
```

Now, assuming your script is on the host in a file called `script.lua`, you want to load that into dockerised Redis:

```
docker exec -i some-redis redis-cli -x script load < script.lua
```

That will return a SHA sum - I got 93126620988a563ac9dd347d02a9cdbbbeaee3c1 - and you can then run the script with:

```
docker exec -i some-redis redis-cli EVALSHA 93126620988a563ac9dd347d02a9cdbbbeaee3c1 0
PONG
```

---

If you want to automate the capture of the SHA sum and its subsequent use:

```
sha=$(docker exec -i some-redis redis-cli -x script load < script.lua)
```

Then:

```
docker exec -i some-redis redis-cli EVALSHA $sha 0
PONG
```